Disk-sound after mounting
I bought a new USB3 16TB harddisk - not an SSD but the old-style spinning disks.
Seagate Expansion 16TB HDD
I created a full-disk-partition formatted with ext4 - 14TB after formatting.
Now when I mount it I recognize a tok-tok-tok sound. If I unmount it it disappears instantly. It is silent if if is just plugged in but not mounted.
What is that? Some disk-access mechanism of the OS or what? Caching?
If I do on a Debian10 it happends 2x/s.
If I mount on a Debian 12 it happens once every 3s.

I'm guessing it is actually 14 TiB (around 15 TB) after formatting. Disks are marketed in decimal (SI) units [as that gives bigger numbers] but many tools like df -h report power-of-two (IEC) units. df -H would show SI instead.

It's probably the ext4 "lazy inode table init" feature continuing the format process in background.
The 'Ext' filesystems statically allocate a certain percentage of the disk space for inodes, and it may take a while to initialize them on a large HDD (as it is necessary to zero a large chunk of the disk), e.g. creating an Ext2 or Ext3 filesystem could take tens of minutes (I've even heard hours).
With Ext4, however, mkfs.ext4 by default doesn't zero out all inodes when creating the filesystem, instead a kernel thread does the job in background while the filesystem is already mounted; that way it's ready for use almost immediately.
You can either reformat using mkfs.ext4 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0 or just wait until it finishes the job.

Is there some progress viewable? Indeed I was wondering why gparted formatted so quickly.

Doesn't seem like it is. If you see a ext4lazyinit kthread running, then it's still in progress, but neither the kernel nor tune2fs seem to tell exactly how far in progress it is.

Thank you very much!

@u1686_grawity And it kind of makes sense that they wouldn’t go to the trouble of doing so, because people who care are very likely to be the same people who need deterministic behavior from first mount, and therefore would be disabling lazy initialization anyway (or possibly using a filesystem that doesn’t need static inode tables).

@AustinHemmelgarn: Are you saying that people only care about things for business reasons? Not, say, out of curiosity or general desire to know whether their system is functioning as it should?

@u1686_grawity I’m saying that the developers likely assumed that it was not worth implementing a progress reporting mechanism, given that the people who have an actual need for that knowledge from an engineering perspective are likely to just not use the lazy initialization in the first place.
